# Using custom taxonomies with wp_get_archives()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to get a yearly archive of my posts with a post type of 'foi'.

Here is my code:

```php
wp_get_archives(
    array(
        'post_type'       => 'foi',
        'type'            => 'yearly',
        'limit'           => '10',
        'show_post_count' => 'true'
    )
);
```

I have a taxonomy set-up for the post type **foi** and I would like to use that in the wp_get_archives() function somehow. An example would be to show the yearly archive for all posts with a post type of **foi** but also with a taxonomy of **document**.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: This might be what you need: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/getarchives_where/#user-contributed-notes

Answer (score 2):

You get it using filter like below:

In templates/custom-archive-template.php

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'custom_archive_by_category_where' );
add_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'custom_archive_by_category_join' );
 
$args = array();
 
wp_get_archives(
  array(
    'type'            => 'yearly',
    'format'          => 'option',
    'post_type'       => 'news',
  )
);
 
remove_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'custom_archive_by_category_where' );
remove_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'custom_archive_by_category_join' );
```

In functions.php:

```
function custom_archive_by_category_join( $x ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $x . " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)";
}
 
function custom_archive_by_category_where($x) {
    global $wpdb;
    $current_term_slug = get_query_var( 'news_category' );
 
    if (!empty($current_term_slug)) {
        $current_term = get_term_by('slug', $current_term_slug, 'news_category');
 
        if (is_wp_error($current_term) ) {
            return $x;
        }
 
        $current_term_id = $current_term->term_id;
 
        return $x . " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'news_category' AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN ($current_term_id)";
 
    }
 
    return $x;
}
```

Please change `news_category` to your desire category slug.
Originally posted on: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/#div-comment-3182

Comment: You mention that I need to change 'news_category' to my category slug but I am using a custom taxonomy. The URL structure for my taxonomy is /release/taxonomy-slug/. Obviously taxonomy-slug will change depending on which taxonomy is selected / active... Where does that leave me?

Comment: I mean your category.  like product_category, dummy_category.